# Local admin rights for hundreds of PCs

Tags: windows-10, administrator, active-directory, group-policy, local

I have been given a task to onboard several hundreds of computers for their users. This task has 3 main points:

1) Installing Windows 10 on each computer from a USB key.

2) Going into Active Directory and adding some very predictable lines manually to every single PC in the Attribute Editor section.

3) Logging into every single machine as domain admin and setting up its prospective user as local admin (the user should be local admin on their machine only).

Is there a more intelligent way to do points 2) and 3) through automated means, e.g. mass upload, group policy etc.? I do not believe this has to be done for each individual asset manually.

Comment: depending on the server version, 2; powershell. 3; you could use group policy here to assign the users group local admin. that means every user in the domain is local admin on every pc.

Comment: Reg. 3), the security requires that each user is admin only on his PC

Comment: Nope, then it becomes a manual job. If the pc's are in the domain, you can use Computer Management and connect to each pc remotely to assign the user, but it is going to be a manual job.

Comment: Interesting - while manual job still, it would still prevent me having to physically get hold of each PC, switch it on, restart it, log in again, shut down and then again storing the PC.

Comment: "the user should be local admin on their machine only" - You do understand this is a huge security risk right?  It means they can unplug the network cable, login as the cached account in theory, and change any group policy they want.

Comment: @Ramhound: Some tasks require local admin rights. There is no way around this and the OP's way to achieve it is perfectly fine. Unless there is a sophisticated lockdown in place users could also "hack" the built-in Administrator account or just reinstall Windows outright.

Comment: @DanielB Very few daily tasks actually requires elevated permissions

Comment: @Ramhound This is not for me to decide and there is a fair bit of office politics behind all this. I advocated a different solution entirely but "it was not possible" so here I am, responsible for the deployment described above. And I just want to know if there is a way I could go about it smarter because currently my impression is the responsible party is either lying outright (and in doing so wasting company resources) or highly incompetent (and in doing so wasting company resources).